# IntelliJ JSF basic project doesn't work in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, http-status-code-404

I created a new JSF-PrimeFaces project in IntelliJ IDEA using Tomcat 9, it doesn't work.

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:body>
      <h:form>
         <p:panel header="Keyboard Demo">
            <p:keyboard value="#{keyboardBean.value}"/>
         </p:panel>
         <p:commandButton value="Submit"/>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

KeyBoardBean.java

```
package main;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class KeyBoardBean {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        System.out.println("KeyboardBean::reading value: " +value);
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        System.out.println("KeyboardBean::setting value: " +value);
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I run Tomcat this is what I got:

[image: Error 404]

What I have missed? Is my IDEA installation broken?

EDIT: I tried using Tomcat 8, I have made a new default project using the Primefaces template, Run and the same error above appears, here's the server output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin\catalina.bat" run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Antonio\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_8_untitled"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.101 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.8
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.102 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 3 2016 21:14:13 UTC
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.102 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.8.0
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.102 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Antonio\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_8_untitled
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.103 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Antonio\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_8_untitled\conf\logging.properties
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Antonio\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_5_8_untitled
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\temp
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR version 1.5.2.
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.104 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
17-Nov-2016 19:03:27.952 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.016 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.057 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.058 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.059 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.059 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1134 ms
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.073 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.073 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.8
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.079 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.084 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
17-Nov-2016 19:03:28.086 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 26 ms
17-Nov-2016 19:03:38.080 INFORMAZIONI [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\webapps\manager
17-Nov-2016 19:03:38.267 INFORMAZIONI [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\webapps\manager has finished in 187 ms
[2016-11-17 07:03:54,997] Artifact untitled:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Connected to server
[2016-11-17 07:03:55,018] Artifact untitled:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2016-11-17 07:03:55,073] Artifact untitled:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-11-17 07:03:55,074] Artifact untitled:war exploded: Deploy took 56 milliseconds
```

[Project.rar](https://mega.nz/#!o4N3mDJD!or-OR8WYX0YVetr_ggAnXknEFc6vFhxzwKV57GqbJ9M)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the context root of your web application.
By default, it uses the filename of the war if not specified but if your war changes because of version change, it is clumsy to change the url of the application for application clients. So, it is a best practice to configure the context root of your application.

Instead of `localhost:8080/index.html`, it would be `localhost:8080/yourApp/index.html`

A`context.xml` file in the `META-INF` folder of you WAR should be present when the war is deployed. If you have a `META-INF` folder in the source of your project, it may do the job.
 Otherwise, you should detail how you build your war.

In this file, specify the docbase which is the root context in this way :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context
  docBase="yourApp">
</Context>
```

From the [official doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) :

> In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application
>   files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be
>   copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>   application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.

Besides, specifying `index.html` in your browser should not be required since one of default welcome-file page is `index.html`.

Comment: Element "context-root" not allowed here

Comment: where is META-INF? I have only WEB-INF

Comment: You should understand basis before I think

Comment: What basis do I need to run a default basic project created by default by IDEA? It happens the same if I create a new simple Hello Workd project with Primefaces, it always says No resource found, no matter what URL I put into the browser

Comment: Add server output in your post. Needed information could be found hère.

Comment: Done, check the first post.

Comment: I added the project .rar

Comment: These are IntelliJ logs and not tomcat logs. Go to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\logs dir. You should have a file catalina..**.log. If you have several files, take the last modified file.

Comment: There's no log files in there.

Comment: Probably an IntelliJ side effect. The best for you would be to use a building tool to build and package your project (Maven or Gradle for example) . In this way, it would be much more simple. Anyway, I looked in your RAR which contains source code. So, in your project in IntelliJ, in the web folder, create a `META-INF` folder and a `context.xml` file as I explained in my answer. Then redeploy the component. If you have no error, the application should be deployed here : `localhost:8080/yourApp`. I don't know if it will work because I don't know the IntelliJ process to package the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary oh what you need to do.

Download tomcat 10 tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi

I downloaded the 64-bit Windows zip file so I can easily restart the server from intellij dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.14/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.14-windows-x64.zip

Extract the folder to an easy to remember location

In intellij create a New Project and then select 'Java Enterprise' -> Name Project -> Under Project template: select Web application -> Under Application server select Tomcat (If Tomcat is not an option you can click new and navigate to the root directory where you extracted the tomcat zip. If you have already built the project before setting up your Application server then I have detailed instructions below explaining how to add tomcat server to your Java Enterprise project. If your project is not Java Enterprise then START OVER)

Language: Java

Build system: Maven

Test framework: JUnit

pick whatever you want for the last 3 options and click Next

Under Specifications I personally selected Full Platform but I think you can get away with just selecting Server Faces, Servlet and Enterprise Java Beans (EJB)

Under Implementations I selected everything labeled Apache and Mojarra Server Faces

Click Finish

Allow Project to build then you will need to make some additions to a few files

*Before doing the next step I highly suggest adding a quick button to clean install your project. You will need to do this A LOT. To add then button in the top right of your intellij window you will see a drop down window. it may say "Edit Configurations" or Tomcat... (if you added tomcat at the project creation stage). Click the drop down and select Edit Configurations, click the plus in the top left of the window that pops up, Select "Maven". You can name it Build (Project Name) in the Command line field (May be labeled as Command line or be under the word Run with the words "Command Line" in grey (its the same field)).  Type "clean install" do this without the quotes. just clean 'space' install then click Apply then OK. Now all you will need to do is click the green triangle next to the drop down to clean install.

In your pom.xml file add the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- This dependency is here but its the wrong version so deleted it or comment it out -->
<!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16</version>
    </dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Next navigate to your web.xml file located in src-> main-> webapp-> WEB-INF and replace all the text with this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
         jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0"
         metadata-complete="true">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

Now refresh your Maven so that it can download the new dependencies. To do this click the Maven tab on the far right of the intellij window and click the refresh button. "Looks kinda like the recycle symbol" or two arrows circling each other. Now clean install your project. If you did not set up the button then you will need to open the Maven tab then expand the file that shares your project name then expand Lifecycle the double click "clean" once it finishes double click "install" (this is why its better to make the build button this gets annoying)

Finally start your tomcat server. Once the server is deployed it should open a browser window and run the default index.jsp file it says "Hello World!" and there is a link saying "Hello Servlet"

Since you are working on *.xhtml files I'm sure you will be wanting to actually use .xhtml files and not .jsp to make sure your project can work with .xhtml files please create one inside the webapp directory. The easiest way is to right click the webapp folder and select New -> JSF/Facelets. Then make your hello world file Something quick and simple. Finally the last two things, to navigate to your .xhtml file shut down the tomcat server, clean install project, redeploy tomcat server and at the end of the URL just type the file name you created including the .xhtml extension. This should take you to your Hello World file.

Last thing if you want to change which page gets loaded when your Tomcat server is deployed simply add this additional tag to your web.xml file.

The welcome file can be whatever you want to link to You can also have multiple files in this list so if one is missing the server will move down the list until it finds one that does exist.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello-world.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In intellij go to "Run/Debug Configurations click the `+` symbol in the top left of the window, select tomcat local. Name the server, then click the "Configure..." button to the right of the Application server: field. In the Application Servers window that pops up Click Tomcat Home: and navigate to the root directory of wherever you extracted the Tomcat 10 zip file. Example C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.0.14. If the rest of the fields populate then you did it correctly. Click Ok

Next Click the Deployment tab below the server name. Click the `+` and select Artifact. Then click the artifact that ends in war exploded (actually it worked with either but that's the one I chose)